# Compare rows value

Tags: sql-server

```
ID  mobileno    dateofregistration        registrationstate
44  1674174925  2011-04-18 10:17:30.670     0
45  1677864168  2011-04-18 10:20:22.450     1
46  1677864161  2011-04-18 20:47:35.293     0
47  1674174925  2011-04-19 09:28:55.200     1
48  1674174925  2011-04-19 09:28:56.200     0
49  1674174925  2011-04-19 09:28:57.200     1
50  1674174925  2011-04-18 10:17:30.670     0
51  1677864168  2011-04-18 10:20:22.450     1
52  1677864161  2011-04-20 20:47:35.293     0
53  1674174925  2011-04-22 09:28:55.200     1
54  1674174925  2011-04-28 09:28:56.200     0
55  1674174925  2011-04-28 09:28:57.200     1
```

My problem is how to count the rows with the following conditions:

`registrationstate = 1` and `datediff(day,dateofregistration) > 30` for the individual mobile no.

Here the result will be 1

Comment: What do you mean by "the result will be 1" ? "1" of what?? What are you looking for - the **count** of mobile no. that match that criteria (I get 2 for that.....) or what??? Not clear at all.....

Answer (score 0):

first of all, `datediff` requires 3 arguments

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

I assume that you want to compare with today's date, so you can use `getdate()`

```
select * from yourtable
where registrationstate = 1
and datediff( day, dateofregistration,  getdate() ) > 30
```

if `getdate()` return 2011-05-04 , you will get the following output

```
------------------------------------------------------------
ID  mobileno    dateofregistration        registrationstate
------------------------------------------------------------
45  1677864168  2011-04-18 10:20:22.450     1
47  1674174925  2011-04-19 09:28:55.200     1
49  1674174925  2011-04-19 09:28:57.200     1
51  1677864168  2011-04-18 10:20:22.450     1
53  1674174925  2011-04-22 09:28:55.200     1
55  1674174925  2011-04-28 09:28:57.200     1
------------------------------------------------------------
```

now you want to group the results by `mobileno` and also return the number of rows per group. You can use the `COUNT(*)` aggregate function to return the number of rows per group

```
select COUNT(*) as total, mobileno from yourtable
where registrationstate = 1
and datediff( day, dateofregistration,  getdate() ) > 30
group by mobileno
```

you will get the following output

```
------------------------------------------------------------
mobileno      total
------------------------------------------------------------
1677864168    2
1674174925    4
------------------------------------------------------------
```